Can the dikaryotic mycelium of Agaricus bisporus develop chlamydospores under certain conditions?
In 2022, a 12th grade student from a private school in Colombia made the claim  about Agaricus bisporus:

When in unfavorable conditions, the dikaryotic mycelium will develop the chlamydospores

The essay cites this article on biologydiscussion.com. (Elsewhere in the report, there's also a citation of Tridge 2020 Industry Report:
Mushroom, however that makes no mention of chlamydospores.)
Does the  dikaryotic mycelium of this species develop chlamydospores under certain conditions?

@DanGetz: I think you are focussing on the wrong aspect. We don't expect references in questions to be rigorous. We expect them to be widely believed. This question doesn't appear to be notable, and I would close it, but it already has a high quality answer.

@DanGetz: How is my edit?

According to a photocopied book chapter on Agaricus, hosted by the Government Arts College for Women, Salem, India, at page 156:

Alexopoulos (1952) has stated that the secondary mycelium produces chlamydospores.

"Alexopouls" is almost certainly Constantine John Alexopoulos who published his first edition of Introductory Mycology in 1952.
On page 455 Alexopoulos writes:

The dikaryotic mycelium bears clamp connections and produces chlamydospores

however, this is in reference to a different genus.
On page 509 Alexopoulos writes:

Some species, such as Agaricus campestris, produce chlamydospores.

SUCCESSIVE BOTANY FOR B. Sc Part 1 - Based on Kashmir University Syllabus says in section 1.11.15.1 Agaricus:

chlamydospores develop in terminal or intercalary positions on the secondary mycelium

Botany: An Introduction To Plant Biology says in the Agaricus section on page 158:

chlamydospores originate on dikaryotic mycelium, which produces dikaryotic mycelium upon germination in favorable conditions. The chlamydospores on the secondary mycelium germinate at the tip or in the intercalary space and then create more mycelium.


So does agaricus bisporus produce chlamydospores

@Harrychink I don't have any evidence that it does.  Agaricus campestris is the closest I see so far.
